# Atmel Studio AtTiny104 - Simple code

Tags: c, input, output, adc, atmelstudio

I am a beginner in C programming and have some problems with the following code:

My project is simple: 
While inputs i2 high or i3 high or i4 (analog value) < 700
Then output o1 is high
Else If i1 is high 
Then o1 is low 
Else o1 is high

My code:

```
#define F_CPU 8000000UL
#include <avr/io.h>
#include <util/delay.h>
#include "iomacros.h"

int main(void) {

    // Change to 8MHz clock speed (Clock Division = 1)
    CCP = 0xD8;
    CLKPSR = 0x00;

    // Define pins
    #define OUTPUT_1 1,A
    #define INPUT_1 2,A
    #define INPUT_2 3,A
    #define INPUT_3 4,A

    // Set up the ADC
    ADCSRA |= (1 << ADEN) | (1 << ADPS2); // Enable ADC = 16
    ADMUX |= (1 << MUX1) | (1 << MUX0); // Connect ADC3 input on PA6
    DIDR0 |= (1 << ADC3D); // Power saving feature

    out(OUTPUT_1); // set OUTPUT_1 as an output

    inp(INPUT_1); // set INPUT_1 as an input
    pullup(INPUT_1); // activate pullup for INPUT_1

    inp(INPUT_2); // set INPUT_1 as an input
    pullup(INPUT_2); // activate pullup for INPUT_2

    inp(INPUT_3); // set INPUT_1 as an input
    pullup(INPUT_3); // activate pullup for INPUT_3
    on(OUTPUT_1);

    // forever loop
    while (1) {

        ADCSRA |= (1 << ADSC); // start single conversion
        while (ADCSRA & (1 << ADSC)) {} // wait until conversion is done
        uint16_t INPUT_4 = ADCL | (ADCH << 8); // Store in INPUT_4

        if (get(INPUT_2) == 1 || get(INPUT_3) == 1 || INPUT_4 > 800) {
            on(OUTPUT_1);
            } else {
            if (get(INPUT_1) == 1) {
                off(OUTPUT_1);
                } else {
                on(OUTPUT_1);
            }
        }
        _delay_ms(100);
    }

}
```

From some reason i1 disables o1 if high even when if (get(INPUT_2) == 1 || get(INPUT_3) == 1 || INPUT_4 > 800) is true. Some help apreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Shtap with the compound boolean expressions.  Use temp booleans for the results from 'get(INPUT_2) == 1' etc.  Then OR the temps together in your if statement.  Then run under your debugger.  Then see which boolean/s is/are true that should not be.

Answer (score 0):

there is a missing parenthesis in this line:

> if (get(INPUT_1)==1{

should be:

> if (get(INPUT_1)==1){

Your code is not properlly indented, errors are not easy to detect.

Comment: I'm surprised it compiles:(

Comment: This is the last iteration of the code, but i forgot to add that parenthesis, before i posted the code here the parenthesis was there and the code compiles without errors or warnings, i am able to flash it. The problem is that even when i2,i3,i4 is high, i1 still disables o1 if high

Comment: Also what kind of approach will you recommend. This setup will be running almost 20 hours every day

Comment: I am too. Using a correct editor should allow to indent everything correctly and eliminate most of the mistakes.

Comment: There is a strange behaviour, the code ignores    if (get(INPUT_2) == 1 || get(INPUT_3) == 1 || INPUT_4 > 800) condition even if all are true(high) and jumps to else

Comment: There is no source for the 'get' operation: is it a macro or a function? Also note there is no semi-colon in the 'on(OUTPUT_1)' instruction before 'while(1)'. The '}}' is dubious also.

Comment: Yeah - the poor indentation makes things very confusing;(

Comment: I copied everything in emacs and indented everything, it is more clear now ;-)

Comment: No, it really is not:(

Comment: I solved the indentation and simple errors like parathesis and ; .
Code compiles OK but the problem is still present.
Can it be from the choosing of the pins ?
SOIC14 pinout: [link]https://3.bp.blogspot.com/-K0i0Nog_6aA/Vuy_gZ1g6wI/AAAAAAAAAjk/mOH9CfmZry862JC8gvMSVsR8pSaS5zeOA/s1600/attiny102_104_pinouts.png

Comment: There are two 'else' at the same level and two '}}'.  It looks terrible, and it's difficult to follow, and it's easy to make flow-of-control errors.:(

Comment: Also, get rid or the compound boolean expression, as I suggested earlier.